# why pods not getting incoming connections

Tags: kubernetes

I am making my first steps with Kubernetes and I have some difficulties.

I have a pod with it's service defined as NodePort at port 30010.

I have a load balancer configured in front of this Kubernetes cluster where port 8443 directs traffic to this 30010 port.

when I try to access this pod from outside the cluster to port 8443 the pod is not getting any connections but I can see the incoming connections via tcptrack in the host in port 30010 with means the load balancer is doing it's job.

when I do curl -k https://127.0.0.1:30010 in the host I get a response from the pods.

what am I missing?
how can I debug it?

thanks

Comment: Looks like an LB is configured in `http/https` mode. It should be switched to `tcp` mode if it's possible.

Comment: I will try and update. thanks